# Do I need an api key for yahoo maps and if so how do I get it?

Tags: yahoo-maps

I want to add yahoo maps to my web page do I need an api key?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need an application id. In the [examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/ajax/) there is a link to explaining how to [obtain one](http://developer.yahoo.com/wsregapp/).

Comment: what about a developer api key

Comment: i mean for debugging its not actually on  a server just on xammp

Comment: @will A, even for debugging you still need a key to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what functionality you want to use, I believe that you do. You need to register your application to get a key: [Yahoo Application Registration](https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/wsregapp/)